# What is the proper way to get some specific user attributes from Active Directory via LDAP C API?

Tags: c, windows, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get some user attributes from Active Directry using Windows LDAP API. I am using:

- Active Directory Version: The one that comes with Windows Server 2012
- LDAP version: 3
- Wldap32.lib version: The one that comes with Windows 10 x64

Eg:

```
PCHAR myAttributes[4];

myAttributes[0] = "DistinguishedName";
myAttributes[1] = "DisplayName";
myAttributes[2] = "PasswordExpired";
myAttributes[3] = "mail";

ldap_search_s(
    myLdapConnection,   // Ldap connection
    myDomain,           // DN to start search
    LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, // Scope
    myFilter,           // Filter
    myAttributes,       // Retrieve list of attributes
    0,                  // Get both attributes and values
    &mySearchResult     // [out] Search results
);
```

It returns `DistinguishedName`, `DisplayName` and `mail` attributes, but does not reuturn the `PasswordExpired` attribute.

I queried with some other attributes and it looks like it does not return attributes with boolean values as well as the `EmailAddress` attribute.

1. Why does it not return `PasswordExpired` attribute?
2. What about `EmailAddress` ?
3. Is there a difference between `EmailAddress` and `mail` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no PasswordExpired LDAP attribute in Active Directory. To build your query look at this URL for attribute names in standard Active Directory schema https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx. To check if password for given account is expired you'll need to check userAccountControl attribute, which is actually value storing flags of different states of user account https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx. There is IADsUser interface that will translate this all for you in case you don't have to stick just to LDAP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746343(v=vs.85).aspx
2. You will find current primary email address in mail attribute. There is no EmailAddress LDAP attribute, unless you meant E-mail-Addresses which is CN for the same schema attribute as mail, so no difference there.
3. See above. In general if you do not have compelling reason to stick just to C/LDAP I'd recommend you to use .Net Framework instead. Otherwise you have a lot of work ahead of you - not just interpreting bit flags like in case of password expiration but possibly also with different authentication methods, different structures capturing time and date, accounting for timezones, UTF, chasing referrals and other stuff you might need depending on complexity of what you want to achieve. You will be productive much faster in .Net Framework. See DirectoryServices https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481534(v=vs.110).aspx namespace or Security namespace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481561(v=vs.110).aspx for details.